# Can I say $B/x^nB$ is a projective $R[[x]]/x^n$-module, $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a regular ring and $B$ be an $R$-module.

If $B/x^nB$ be a projective $R[x]/x^n$-module, then can I say $B/x^nB$ is a projective $R[[x]]/x^n$-module, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

I think think $R[[x]]$ is the inverse limit or the completion of $R[x]/x^n$ with respect to $x$-adic topology. So the result holds, i think.

Please help me to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not really matter that the formal power series ring is the inverse limit of these as the two rings $R[x]/(x^n)$ and $R[[x]]/(x^n)$ are just isomorphic (both consist of polynomials in one variable over $R$ up to degree $n-1$). And yes, therefore your module is also projective over $R[[x]]/(x^n)$.

Comment: oh!, I just missed to think this isomorphic property. Thank you for nice answer